# Разместить кнопки в меню на одинаковое растояние и до конца экрана при разных разширениях

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте, как можно с помощью css разместить кнопки на нижнем меню нормально, чтобы при сжатии экрана они просто сближались друг к другуи когда уже силшком маленький экран падали вниз. Пробовал через % но угадывать, тыкать... да и падать тогда они начинают очень быстро. И + надо чтобы слева и справа был маленький отступ на ul
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте flex:

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

вам лучше бы bootstrap использовать. А чтобы в зависимости от разрешения экрана изменялись используемые css правила нужно бы использовать блок  [@media{}](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media). ограничение, броузер должен поддерживать стандарты css3.

Comment: если можно обойтись без медиа запросов то надо обходится , ваш бутстрап в топку